# Toggle Button flutter not functioning

Tags: flutter, togglebutton

I am still a beginner in flutter, I am trying to make a small App to allow the user to convert the units from SI to IP units... to I used `ToggleButton`, as a try once the `ToggleButton` toggled a small text at the bottom of the page must be changed, but nothing is happening, can any body help what i did wrong... the code is

```
class ToggleButtonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToggleButtonPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleButtonPageState createState() => _ToggleButtonPageState();
}

class _ToggleButtonPageState extends State<ToggleButtonPage> {
  bool siUnits;
  String siUnitsText;
  String showText;

  List<bool> isSelected2 = [true, false];

  String textShow(String siUnitsText) {
    if (siUnitsText == 'true') {
      showText = 'ooooooo';
    } else {
      showText = 'xxx';
      print('xxx');
    }
    return showText;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: ToggleButtons(
              fillColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              selectedBorderColor: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              children: [
                Text(
                  'SI',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'IP',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  switch (newIndex) {
                    case 0:
                      siUnitsText = 'true';
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      siUnitsText = 'false';
                      break;
                  }

                  for (int index = 0; index < isSelected2.length; index++) {
                    if (index == newIndex) {
                      isSelected2[index] = true;
                    } else {
                      isSelected2[index] = false;
                    }
                  }
                });
                print(siUnitsText);
              },
              isSelected: isSelected2,
            ),
          ),
          Text('Value is equal to  $showText'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also here is a photo for the layout
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showText` variable is initially null. You are not setting `showText` before displaying it in `Text` widget. If `textShow` method is for setting up the `showText` variable, call `textShow` method inside `setState`.